# Selenium Webdriver : Validate httpResponse xml

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I want to validate XML response which is obtained from httpResponse

My Code

```
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(decouplingURL);
 httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(soapRequest));
 System.out.println(soapRequest);
 HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
 System.out.println(httpResponse);
 String resp = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity(),"UTF-8");
 System.out.println(resp);
 String payload = "";
 NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("payload");
 for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
     if (nl.item(i).getNodeType() == org.w3c.dom.Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
         org.w3c.dom.Element nameElement = (org.w3c.dom.Element) nl.item(i);
         payload = nameElement.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().trim();
     }
 }
```

In above code I am getting following response and I want to get @status and validate weather it's value is 1 or not. 
Similarly I have to validate weaher 'charge-method' is 3 or not

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<er-response>
  <payload>
      <subscription id="33517965" status="1">
        <pricepoint id="package:aceklpackage">
          <charge-method>3</charge-method>
          <rate resource="EUR" tax-rate="0.23">30.0</rate>
          <user-group>hover32</user-group>
        </pricepoint>
      </subscription>
  </payload>
</<er-response>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what this question has to do with WebDriver, you're using Apache HttpClient. You can simply use [XPath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html) to extract the elements you want from the xml:

```
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();

Document doc = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(resp.getBytes("UTF-8")));

XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

System.out.printf("Status: %s\n", xPath.evaluate("//subscription/@status", doc));
System.out.printf("Charge Method: %s\n", xPath.evaluate("//charge-method//text()", doc));
```

Result:

```
Status: 1
Charge Method: 3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for solving my issue. Actually I was using this in selenium webdriver so I have added as prefix in my question. But Yes, You are eight. It has nothing to do with Selenium.